# Why won't this C program pick up escaped backslashes?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm doing K&R's Exercise 1-10

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab by `\t`, each backspace by `\b` and each backslash by `\\`. This makes tabs and backspaces visible in an unambiguous way.

I came up with this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int c;
    printf("\n"); // For readability

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        switch (c) {
            case '\t':
                printf("\\t");
                break;
            case '\b':
                printf("\\b");
            case '\\':
                printf("\\");
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c", c);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason, it refuses to touch backslashes. For example, the output from the program when fed a string such as `Hello how\ are you?` is `Hello\thow\ are you?` which means it converted the tab OK, but not the backslash.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can we _please_ at least offer the courtesy of asking if it's homework first? There are numerous people who have been told their questions are homework only to respond that it's self-education. I'm all for tagging them if we're sure but not without confirming. And, if someone lies about it, tough! They'll fail when they hand the work in since any educator not monitoring these sites for plagiarism shouldn't be educating.

Comment: Every educator has to check the internet for every question they set every time they set it before marking? Did I wake up in cloud moron land? Perhaps they just paste each line of each students answers into google. That might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to `printf("\\\\");`, instead of just `printf("\\");`.

Comment: @Aaron: I only hope that a 15K rep SO user would know to tag a question as homework if it were so.

Comment: This is _not_ a solution for homework. It's one minor detail that we can help with since the OP has done the bulk of the work. Unless the homework is "Why won’t this C program pick up escaped backslashes?" in which case I fear for the IT industry in the future :-) On top of that, the HW tag was added by someone else.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just thought about it, and realised printing 2 `\\` would require me to escape them both. Whoops! – alex 1 hour ago

Answer (score 2):

You should be printing the backslash **and** its escape.

Currently you're just printing the backslash - here you're escaping the second backslash which would otherwise escape the closing double quote:

```
printf("\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf("\\\\")`

Comment: In this case it's OK even if it's homework - he pasted working code and showed that he made an effort to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 2):

What does the C compiler do when it finds `\\` in the source?

Comment: Hint: don't be vague for non-homework :-) {Just a subtle jab, please don't take offence}.